# Proof two solutions of a differential equation are linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Given two solutions for a second order diferential equation:

$y(x)=e^{a x}$ and $y(x)=x e^{a x}$

How to show these are linear independent?

I procede as follow applying the definition of linear independence:

$A e^{a x} + B x e^{a x} = 0$ $ \forall x$

Then:

$A  + B x  = 0$

Here i dont know exactly how to conclude in a "formal" way that $A=B=0$ are the only solutions and hence the two functions are linear independent.

Comment: The first equation you had should be true for all $x$ (this is important). Therefore, if you take derivatives on both sides you get an equation that should also be true for all $x$. You get get an extra equation to work with.

Comment: The determinant of the system you get is called the [Wronskian]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian} of the two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A, B$ are not equal to $0$. Then you can solve for $x$. Now choose a different value for $x$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

The independence of two solutions means that
$$\begin{array}{|cc|}
y_1&y_2\\y'_1&y'_2\\
\end{array}\ne 0$$

Comment: Why is that statement true? @Semsem

Comment: Because in this case there is a non-zero solution for $A$ and $B$.